# How is the uncertainty relation generalized to mixed states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, density-operator

If a system is in a pure state $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ we have
$$\sigma_A\sigma_B\geq\frac{1}{2}|\langle[A,B]\rangle|.$$
Generalize this and find an uncertainty relation for an arbitrary mixed state $\rho$.

Comment: Have you reviewed [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Mixed_states)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: One method to prove [HUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) for mixed states from HUP for pure states is to use the [purification trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purification_of_quantum_state).

Comment: The most obvious purification I can think of for a mixed state $\rho=\sum_n p_n|n\rangle\langle n|$ is $\psi=\sum_n \sqrt{p_n}|n,n\rangle$ which eventually yields $\sigma_A\sigma_B\geq\frac{1}{2}|\sum_{n,m}\sqrt{p_np_m}\langle n,n|[A,B]|m,m\rangle|$
I don't see any obvious way to proceed. Could you (or someone) say if there is a $neat$ expression at all?

Comment: By the way, I didn't make any specific use of purification. The same result could've been achieved by taking expected values any way. So I guess I'm missing something